# US rollover IRA for non-resident alien

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, non-resident

I am not a US citizen, and I am currently not resident in the US.  I lived and worked in the US between 2014 and 2016 and I have a 401(k) from that time.  The 401(k) plan is being terminated and I am being asked to complete a distribution form.

Is it possible to open a rollover IRA as a non-resident alien of the US (and transfer the funds to this account)?  Or am I now forced to withdraw to a cash account (with the income tax withholding and early withdrawal penalty)?

Comment: The financial institution that managed the 401(k) plan would be my first stop to make it a rollover IRA.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the law  to prohibit you from opening an IRA as a non-resident or from rolling over from another qualified plan.

However, many custodians do not allow non-residents to have accounts with them as a general rule. So you'll need to shop around for an IRA custodian who'd allow you to have an account with them.

Comment: Thanks @littleadv.  Are you aware of any specific such custodians?  I've tried a few and have not yet found one that caters to non-resident aliens.